# Appending String from a File into an Array and parsing it

Tags: java, serialization, deserialization, objectoutputstream

I am trying to make a saving/loading of settings for my GUI.

So far, I've got saving, using Properties:

```
Properties prop = new Properties();                   
prop.setProperty("a", Boolean.valueOf(boxRandomMouse.isSelected()).toString());  
prop.setProperty("b", listModelPath.toString());
```

The problem I've got here, is that I am saving `listModelPath` of my `JList` into `String`:

```
public static DefaultListModel<String> listModelPath;
```

In my file under property `b`. I can't find any way to load back and parse this `listModelPath` into my desired type, which is `Position`.

The class, `Position`, can be initialised with below constractor:

```
Position newPos = new Position(int x, int y, int z);
```

or for array:

```
public Position[] toTown = new Position[] {
            new Position(3094, 3491, 0), new Position(3088, 3487, 0),
            new Position(3080, 3475, 0)};
```

This is how the `String` of `listModelPath` looks when It's been saved into the file

```
c=[[x\=3094, y\=3491, z\=0], [x\=3092, y\=3491, z\=0], [x\=3090, y\=3491, z\=0], [x\=3088, y\=3490, z\=0], [x\=3086, y\=3488, z\=0], [x\=3084, y\=3486, z\=0], [x\=3082, y\=3484, z\=0], [x\=3081, y\=3482, z\=0], [x\=3080, y\=3481, z\=0], [x\=3080, y\=3479, z\=0], [x\=3080, y\=3477, z\=0], [x\=2045, y\=5194, z\=0], [x\=2044, y\=5192, z\=0], [x\=2042, y\=5190, z\=0], [x\=2041, y\=5189, z\=0]]
```

I need to figure out a way to parse the String above, into my Positions, or somehow find a way to save this array to a File, which I honestly have no idea how to do.

I've tried doing this numerously on different ways, always failing, so that's why I'm here.
Hopefully you guys knows how to handle a situation I have here.

PS. I have just started reading about serialization, perhaps it is the way to go? Would it allow me to save the array I have dynamically created in the application in the file without converting it to string and back from string?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can serialize your `listModelPath` object sending it then to file as an **Object** which will then let you read it as an Object then cast it back to its real `Class`.

This can be done by chaining an `ObjectOutputSteam` to an underlying stream such as a `FileOutputStream` then writing the Obejet to it (`Position[]`)

```
public void writePositions() throws IOException, ClassNotFoundException {
  File file = new File("positions.ser");
  FileOutputStream outFile = new FileOutputStream(file);
  ObjectOutputStream outStream = new ObjectOutputStream(outFile);
  public Position[] toTown = new Position[] {
      new Position(3094, 3491, 0), 
      new Position(3088, 3487, 0),
      new Position(3080, 3475, 0)};
  outStream.writeObject(toTown);
  outStream.close();
  outFile.close();
}
```

You can the read your serialized array of `Position` back from the file it was written to, *positions.ser* like below:

```
public void readPositions() throws IOException, ClassNotFoundException {
  File file = new File("positions.ser");
  FileInputStream inFile = new FileInputStream(file);
  ObjectInputStream inStream = new ObjectInputStream(inFile);
  Position[] toTown = (Position[]) inStream.readObject());
  for(int i = 0; i < toTown.length; i++) {
    System.out.println(toTown[i]);
  }
  inStream.close();
  inFile.close();
  file.delete();
}
```

You should note that the `Position` class should be `Serializable`, otherwise the JVM won't let you send any object of this type back and forth to an in memory file or even through any stream.

I'm not really sure if I have well understood the main matter concerning the `listModelPath` and how it relates to the `Position` array but you shoul provide more informations, especially how you are creating the `listModelPath` instance.

### Edit (Save many objects with different types):

You can, not only save one `Object`, but as many as you want and wathever type they are. When loading back the objects to the JVM, they should be read in the same order they were written in to avoid a `ClassCastException`:

```
public void writePositions() throws IOException, ClassNotFoundException {
  ...
  public Position[] toTown = new Position[] {
      new Position(3094, 3491, 0), 
      new Position(3088, 3487, 0),
      new Position(3080, 3475, 0)};
  outStream.writeObject(toTown); //Write the array of Position
  boolean selected = boxRandomMouse.isSelected();
  outStream.writeObject(selected); //Write the Boolean Object
  ...
}

public void readPositions() throws IOException, ClassNotFoundException {
  ...
  Position[] toTown = (Position[]) inStream.readObject()); //Read the array of Position which was written first
  for(int i = 0; i < toTown.length; i++) {
    System.out.println(toTown[i]);
  }
  boolean selected = (boolean) inStream.readObject(); //Read the Boolean value which was written in the second order
  // And so on
  ...
}
```

Comment: Thanks, this answered everything.

Comment: @BlackDynamite you are always welcome... You can even upvote the answer to make eligible for future visitors :)

Comment: I'm afraid I can't, requires 15 reputation score to upvote any answer. I don't think I'll ever have 15 reputation, judging by my knowledge, or rather lack of it in the field of programming. Perhaps in a few years :P

Comment: could you please explain, how would I do this, if I wanted to save multiple objects in that file? For example, how would I save both positions there, and my booleans, how would I CONTROL which is which, because I don't completely understand this. (I'm assuming keeping both Properties which I already have, and this serialized object saving is pointless, so I'd like to save everything as serialized)

Comment: You can save you, as many objects as you want and with any type you need then you can load them back from the file **in the same order they were witten in**. So if you save both a `Boolean` and an array of `Position` you can loas them back in that order. I will update my answer.

Answer (score 0):

You can only have Strings in property files, so you have to find a way to convert `listModelPath` in a inversible way. I think that you could try json ([Gson](https://code.google.com/p/google-gson/) or [Jackson](http://wiki.fasterxml.com/JacksonHome)) whose job is to serialize-deserialize objects to-from String.

I can do no more without source of your `Position` class.